# What is the last menu on the Extras page?

Tags: the-unfinished-swan

In the PS3 game The Unfinished Swan, there is a menu that looks like a book, with one page for each of the five chapters of the game (completed parts can be re-played from this menu).

There is an additional page titled "Extras" that contains three items: "Credits", "Concept Art", and "???".

What is the third menu item on the Extras page? I think it has to be unlocked to be accessed, but how do we unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, the third extra is the "Original Prototype" level the developers created for this game (picture taken from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIpY4YacT94))
[image: The Unifished Swan Extras]

You have to collect all balloons in the game to unlock it. The are several guides about where to find all collectibles, for example [this one](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/164729-the-unfinished-swan-collectibles-guide/).

Answer (score -2):

Lets you play the original prototype it was based on